# could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp version=2.12.0.0'

Tags: gtk, runtime-error, version, filenotfoundexception

Trying to run a GTK GUI test app and get "could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp version=2.12.0.0" but i have gtk+-2.0 ver 2.24.10 installed.

how do i work around this please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First install gtk-sharp using following command

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the reference assembly and add it again to your project, recompile and run it again and check if runs. If it doesn't work download this gtk-sharp version which is the latest from version 2.12 [gtk-sharp-2.12.22](http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.22.msi) and add the reference assembly from the new installation. This download is for windows only if you are using mac or linux try downloading gtk-sharp from the mono web site which comes with all that you need for development and deployment [Mono + GTK](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html). If you are using gtk-sharp on windows you don't need to install the mono framework gtk-sharp should work using pure .net framework.